# ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes NPE

Tags: android

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(ViewGroup.java:1112)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.collectViewAttributes(ViewRootImpl.java:1038)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1304)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5609)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:736)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Running monkey i got this crash, it appeared that mChildren[i] null which is supposed never happened. Or is there any posibility cause that?

Here is where NPE occured in viewgroup:

```
@Override
void dispatchCollectViewAttributes(AttachInfo attachInfo, int visibility) {
    if ((visibility & VISIBILITY_MASK) == VISIBLE) {
        super.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(attachInfo, visibility);
        final int count = mChildrenCount;
        final View[] children = mChildren;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = children[i];
            child.dispatchCollectViewAttributes(attachInfo,
                    visibility | (child.mViewFlags&VISIBILITY_MASK));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, Provide a code snippet of the body where the error occured .

Comment: Running monkey :o normally they jump :D

Comment: @Ivan You don't see any of your class/ package inside the error log trace?

Comment: @Charuක This monkey runs a lot ;)

Comment: @NishanKhadka the log above is all i have and i can't tell where the code is  that caused the error. I just post the method dispatchCollectViewAttributes in viewgroup above, i wonder if it remind you anything

Comment: @Nizam in the log we just dump some message about our program and it point out that it crash in one of our fragment with nothing else. Have you met something like this?

Comment: @Charuක Jump? sorry i can get you.. do you mean it jump to another page?